# Can't email errors for cron job

Tags: cron

I have the following entry running and I receive an email..

```
MAILTO=x.y@googlemail.com
* * * * * echo "blaah"
```

However, when I have this as a cron job, no email is received...

```
MAILTO=x.y@googlemail.com
* * * * * sh /scripts/mysql-backup-bak.sh >> /var/log/mysql-backup.log 2>&1
```

...although the script runs and sends to the log file just fine. 
What I'm ultimately trying to do is have it send an email for any errors. But at this point, I can't get it to send at anytime. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second command doesn't produce any output because all output is redirected to the log file. So there is no output to mail. If you want a mail on errors, create output in case of error.

Like this

```
* * * * * sh /scripts/mysql-backup-bak.sh >> /var/log/mysql-backup.log 2>&1 || echo "something went wrong"
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo when I copy/pasted. I've fixed my post.

Comment: ...but I tried it both with quotes and without, it made no difference.

Comment: I changed the answer.

Comment: Ok, I've modified my statement to look like yours and added a random character to my script to generate an error. No email received. Although, the output doesn't explicitly say "error" when the cron job is running - is that a requirement for cron to assume there's an error? I'm not sure how it decides when there is or isn't an error running the job.

Comment: If I take your line and swap the two statements like this...  `* * * * * echo "something went wrong" || sh /scripts/mysql-backup-bak.sh >> /var/log/mysql-backup.log 2>&1`, it will both send an email and write to the logs. Now I'm just not sure how to get to send an email on errors.

Comment: Never mind, I just realized that I needed to make an error with the cronjob to test your solution, not the script. It worked well. Thank you. I'll look at the script itself and see if I can do something else if the script fails.